# How to see past war table missions?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is there a way to look up which missions I have previously completed on the war table? For example, I can't remember if I sent the chargers to Redcliffe and after that did the Venatori Ally mission thingy (with Josephine getting him to send fake info) and it isn't shown as an icon on the actual table. I need to know if I did this mission, because I want to complete everything in the game.